# How to echo an ARBITRARY string to a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I had a batch file, which (when simplified) looked like this:

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    MD "MyProgram^!"
    MD "MyProgram version 2"
    MD "MyProgram (next version)"
    MD "MyProgram O&O"  

    Del Folders.txt
    Call :AddFoldersRecursive .
EndLocal
Goto :EOF

:AddFoldersRecursive FolderPath
    Echo %~1>>Folders.txt
    For /D %%f In ("%~1\*") Do  Call :AddFoldersRecursive "%%~f"
Goto :EOF
```

It brought up all kinds of errors when facing different kinds of file names in different situations:

- `MyProgram version 2` couldn't be echoed, because `2>>` was interpreted incorrectly.
- `MyProgram (next version)` couldn't be echoed, because parentheses had to be `^` escaped.
- `MyProgram O&O` couldn't be echoed, because of the `&` symbol
- `MyProgram!` couldn't be echoed, because of the `!` symbol

Is there any solution which works for **all** such situations (including combinations and nesting, etc.)?

(ASCII is fine -- I don't *need* Unicode support right now.)

Comment: Just wanted to leave a comment since you had asked this question as a comment on my last answer - but I don't see any _simple_ way to do this without doing some manual escaping.

Comment: @DMan: Interesting, thanks for the comment!

Comment: I'll be amazed if anyone can solve this puzzle - cmd.exe batch files have the worst string handling and the most irregular, half-assed quoting support (apparently cobbled together ad-hoc and by trial and error over the years of implementing cmd.exe). I'm already amazed at the things people successfully do with batch files on Windows when it's more than a simple list of programs to run. I have a hideous monster of a batch file that lets me easily compile simple C/C++ programs with various compilers for testing. It seems to break anytime I just load it in an editor. I hate having to update it.

Comment: Oh yeah - and thanks to Microsoft's decision to standardize on the name "Program Files (x86)", the parenthesis problem is one that has hit me in that batch file every now and again (and not just for "echo").

Comment: @Michael: Funny, I also have a batch file to do the same thing, and it *also* seems to break every once in a while. I'm actually really tempted to try and make a UNIX-style shell script interpreter for Windows with *proper* nesting and quoting, but it's obviously a lot of work... (And yeah, Program Files is another one...)

Comment: I take it your script is sufficiently complicated that `dir /b /ad-l-h > files.txt` is insufficient?

Comment: @Gabe: Yes -- for one thing, I should actually have said `%%~dpnxf` instead of `%%f`, because I need the full paths. I also do some checks inside the `For` loop, which I can't do with a `Dir`.

Comment: Like Gabe, I can't reproduce this issue, the command you've specified works fine for me.  What version of Windows are you using?  Have you actually tried the simplified command to see if it works for you?

Comment: @Harry: You're right, I guess my on-the-spot simplification actually didn't reproduce the issue (probably because I inlined the subroutine I had). I've put up a sample script which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You only get problems when you use percent expansion, %%-FOR-Loop expansion can only fail with exclamation marks, ! delayed expansion can handle all characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** Take 2...

```
For /D %%f In (*) Do (
    Set "Text=%%~dpnxf"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo.!Text!>>files.txt
    EndLocal
)
```

Comment: Already tried: That doesn't work for file names with exclamations, e.g. `Yahoo! Messenger` (yes, I still have it :P)

Comment: You know, that block of code could be replaced by `Dir /B >>files.txt` to achieve the desired result.  But I will endevour to answer the original question!

Comment: Right, but that's only because I was simplifying. :) I'm actually echoing full paths and doing some checks, etc... thanks for the suggestion anyway, though!

Comment: Okay, here's my next attempt.  It seems to cover all of the cases you've listed, plus % symbols.

Comment: Yes, the delayed toggling can handle all special characters, only the `echo.` can fail if there exists a file named `echo` (without extension), better use `echo(` it's safe and it's faster

Comment: @jeb, Hand-E-Food: For some reason, this works in one of my scripts but not in another one. (The `!` sometimes gets stripped off.) Let me see what's wrong and I'll post something when I find out.

Comment: @jeb, Hand-E-Food: AHHHHHHH I **also** need to *disable* delayed expansion in my **`For`** loop's `In` clause!!! Doing that seems to make everything work fine now!! Thanks so much!! I didn't even believe it was possible! :D

Comment: Yes, disable delayed expansion is required, it's obvious :-) To understand why you could read [how the parser works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts/4095133#4095133), I spend many hours to discover this

Answer (score 0):

Enabling delayed expansion eats the exclamation marks, so I disabled it for the output stage. What I did here was copy it to another variable so I could do replacement, then replace the `&` with `^&`. This probably doesn't work for all valid filenames, but does work for your examples:

```
:AddFoldersRecursive FolderPath
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    set "x=%~1"
    Set "x=%x:&=^&%"
    >>Folders.txt Echo %x%
    For /D %%f In ("%~1\*") Do  Call :AddFoldersRecursive "%%~f"
EndLocal
Goto :EOF
```

Comment: Good point, I think the quote example was a result of me messing with my file system a while ago (!), I didn't notice that. But see my sample script, for example, for an example with `&`, which is completely normal.

Comment: Does it matter if you get quotes in for output file? If so, `Echo "%~1">>Folders.txt` should work.

Comment: It definitely *does* matter!!! But that's not even the only issue. I've updated my question (*again*), this time with an example that demonstrates the `MyProgram version 2` problem as well.

Comment: Nice, I just got a script that shows 3/4 of the problems. :D I don't think I can get 4/4 in a single example, but hopefully this is enough.

Comment: OK, how about `>>Folders.txt Echo %~1`?

Comment: That only gets rid of the `2>>` problem. The `!` problem and the `&` problem are still there.

Comment: Yeah, I see. Well, if you look at my edit you'll see that I was able to get your examples to work, but only with significant complications.

Comment: It's easier to enable the delayed expansion AFTER `set "x=%~1"`, then you can use `>>Folders.txt echo !x!` without any problems and no replacements for the special characters.